# PowerBi connect to postgresql with Pythonscript

Tags: python, postgresql, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a Pythonscript that runs fine in Juypter.  If I paste the same script in PowerBi > Transform data > Advanced Editor I get errors that refer to the string literal quotes.
Postgresql expects double quotes and PowerBi wants it to be single quotes.

```
import pandas as pd
import psycopg2

# Define the PostgreSQL connection parameters
conn_params = {
    'host': '127.0.0.1',
    'database': 'test',
    'user': 'postgres',
    'password': 'freya',
    'port': '5432'
}

# Define the SQL query
query = '''
SELECT *
FROM public.address
WHERE ("Enterprise_nbr", "ID") IN (
    SELECT "Enterprise_nbr", MAX("ID")
    FROM public.address
    GROUP BY "Enterprise_nbr")
'''

# Connect to the database and retrieve the data
conn = psycopg2.connect(**conn_params)
data = pd.read_sql(query, conn)

# Close the database connection
conn.close()

# Output the data to Power BI
print(data)
```

If I run the same script but with single quotes in Power Bi I get an error (non-integer constant in GROUP BY:

```
*DataSource.Error: ADO.NET: Python script error.
<pi>C:\Users\freya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py:761: UserWarning: pandas only support SQLAlchemy connectable(engine/connection) ordatabase string URI or sqlite3 DBAPI2 connectionother DBAPI2 objects are not tested, please consider using SQLAlchemy
  warnings.warn(
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: non-integer constant in GROUP BY
LINE 7:     GROUP BY 'Enterprise_nbr')
                     ^
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
pandas.io.sql.DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql '
SELECT *
FROM public.address
WHERE ('Enterprise_nbr', 'ID') IN (
    SELECT 'Enterprise_nbr', MAX('ID')
    FROM public.address
    GROUP BY 'Enterprise_nbr')
': non-integer constant in GROUP BY
LINE 7:     GROUP BY 'Enterprise_nbr')
                     ^
</pi>
Details:
    DataSourceKind=Python
    DataSourcePath=Python
    Message=Python script error.
<pi>C:\Users\freya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py:761: UserWarning: pandas only support SQLAlchemy connectable(engine/connection) ordatabase string URI or sqlite3 DBAPI2 connectionother DBAPI2 objects are not tested, please consider using SQLAlchemy
  warnings.warn(
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: non-integer constant in GROUP BY
LINE 7:     GROUP BY 'Enterprise_nbr')
                     ^
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
pandas.io.sql.DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql '
SELECT *
FROM public.address
WHERE ('Enterprise_nbr', 'ID') IN (
    SELECT 'Enterprise_nbr', MAX('ID')
    FROM public.address
    GROUP BY 'Enterprise_nbr')
': non-integer constant in GROUP BY
LINE 7:     GROUP BY 'Enterprise_nbr')
                     ^
</pi>
    ErrorCode=-2147467259
    ExceptionType=Microsoft.PowerBI.Scripting.Python.Exceptions.PythonScriptRuntimeException*
```

Comment: Why are you not just connecting to PostgreSQL with the specific connector?

Comment: It looks like the `psycopg2 ` package is not supported in Power BI: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/service-python-packages-support . This might be the reason for it to fail.

Comment: The error message says it all: *UserWarning: pandas only support SQLAlchemy connectable(engine/connection) or database string URI or sqlite3 DBAPI2 connection other DBAPI2 objects are not tested, please consider using SQLAlchemy*

Comment: @Marcus ok, I understand, but I don't get why a simple select statement works with psycopg2.  I found a workaround with pandas.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver: ok, I understand, but I don't get why a simple select statement works with psycopg2. I found a workaround with pandas.

Comment: Because you are working in two different clients Juypter != Power Bi.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver: It is true that I did some tests in Juypter.  But I also did several tests in PowerBi/Python and there a sql statement (to postgresql) does NOT work when there are quotes in the sql (postgresql expects ", powerbi wants ' - see original question).  If the sql statement has NO quotes it works fine, so the psycopg2-driver works (see workaround that works).  I just want to try to write script with SQLAlchemy, maybe that will bring a solution.  I don't know, I have no expericence with this.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work with this code using pandas instead of an sql-statement with double or single quotes:

```
import pandas as pd
import psycopg2

# Define the PostgreSQL connection parameters
conn_params = {
    'host': '127.0.0.1',
    'database': 'test',
    'user': 'postgres',
    'password': 'freya',
    'port': '5432'
}

# Define the SQL query
query = '''
SELECT *
FROM public.address
'''

# Connect to the database and retrieve the data
conn = psycopg2.connect(**conn_params)
address_df = pd.read_sql(query, conn)

# Find the maximum ID for each Enterprise_nbr
max_id_df = address_df.groupby("Enterprise_nbr")["ID"].max().reset_index()
# print(max_id_df)

# Merge the original DataFrame with the rows that have the max "ID" for each group
result_df = pd.merge(address_df, max_id_df, on=["Enterprise_nbr", "ID"])
print(result_df)

# Close the database connection
conn.close()
```